# Run startup code when wsgi worker thread restarts

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, wsgi, django-wsgi

I have a django project running a wsgi application using gunicorn. Ahhh too much for the python newbie like me.

I have a below gunicorn command which runs at the application startup.

```
exec ./env/bin/gunicorn $wsgi:application \
    --config djanqloud/gunicorn-prometheus-config.py \
    --name "djanqloud" \
    --workers 3 \
    --timeout 60 \
    --user=defaultuser --group=nogroup \
    --log-level=debug \
    --bind=0.0.0.0:8002
```

Below is my wsgi.py file:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'djanqloud.settings'
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

gunicorn command shown from "ps- -eaf" command in a docker container:

```
/opt/gq-console/env/bin/python2 /opt/gq-console/env/bin/gunicorn wsgi:application --config /opt/gq-console//gunicorn-prometheus-config.py --name djanqloud --workers 3 --timeout 60 --user=gq-console --group=nogroup --log-level=debug --bind=0.0.0.0:8002
```

Their is one simple thread which I create inside django project which are killed when above worker threads are killed.

My question is:

Is there anyway where I can create my threads AGAIN when the above worker threads are auto restarted ?

I have tried to override the get_wsgi_application() function in wsgi.py file but got below error while worker threads are booted:

```
AppImportError: Failed to find application object: 'application'.
```

I am new to python django and wsgi applications so please try to elaborate your answers.

Basically I am looking for a location where I can keep my startup code which runs when the wsgi worker threads are killed and autostarted.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically start your application after server boot or restart automatically your application if gunicorn worker get killed use a process control system such as supervisor. Which will take care of restarting your gunicorn process automatically.

Comment: In my case worker thread are getting restarted automatically. All I need is that where I can put my code so when the worker threads are restarted, my code also get executed. I have tried overriding get_wsgi_application() but failed to do so.